# mysql real escape string error

Tags: mysql

Code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Account(User,
Pw, email)
VALUES('mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[user])',
'$pw','mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[email])
) ")  or die(mysql_error());
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near
>   ''mysql_real_escape_string(123) )' at
>   line 1

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're quoting a PHP command, so it never gets passed to PHP

try this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Account(User, Pw, email) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[user])."', '$pw','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[email])."' ) ") or die(mysql_error());
```

but your $_POST[user] calls might also fail if user isn't a defined constant, so maybe try this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Account(User, Pw, email) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user'])."', '$pw','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."' ) ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: To put it another way - this is the query that is getting passed to MySQL: `INSERT INTO Account(User, Pw, email) VALUES('mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[user])', '$pw','mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[email]) ) ` ... and that is not a valid MySQL query (it contains PHP functions).  This answer fixes the issue.  I'm curious, though, should $pw be escaped as well?

Answer (score 0):

Do not stuff all your code into one line.
You don't have to pay for each additional operator. Write distinctly.

```
$user  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$pw    = mysql_real_escape_string($pw);

$query = "INSERT INTO Account(User,Pw, email) VALUES ('$user','$pw','$email')";
mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);
```